# Accidentally disables all HID devices - can't do anything

Tags: windows, hid, usb-hid

The title says it all. I was experimenting with devcon.exe and I accidentally disabled all HID devices. I have no way of doing anything with my computer except the power button and the windows key, and restarting doesn't seem to be doing anything. I'm a bit stuffed. Is there any way I can fix this?

Comment: Try to boot in safe mode. Try to repair system with external Windows bootable media.

Comment: @Biswa I'm using the surface pro 2 and there is no way to boot into safe mode without explicitly changing options in windows

Comment: Then download recovery image from Microsoft. Enter laptop product name and serial number. **[LINK](https://www.microsoft.com/surface/en-us/support/warranty-service-and-recovery/downloadablerecoveryimage)**.